# why my tkinter scrollbar not working after adding scrollbar?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I have made a user interface but my scrollbar is not working. it is working if i add content statically but when i add frames from button click then it adds new frame but not scrolling to view bottom content or we can say the scroll bar is disabled.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.title("Hello Python")
root.configure(bg="#010523")
root.iconbitmap('logo.ico')
root.geometry("400x500")

frame_main = tk.Frame(root, bg="#010523")
frame_main.grid(sticky='news')

# ********************header frame********************************

header_frame = LabelFrame(frame_main, bg="#010523", border=0, height=100)
header_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='ew')

width =50
height =50
photo= Image.open("logo.png")
photo= photo.resize((width, height),Image.ANTIALIAS)

# create an object of PhotoImage
photoImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo)
photo_label= Label(header_frame, image=photoImg, bg="#010523")
photo_label.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2)


# Label
public_broadcast = Label(header_frame, text="Public broadcast",
                    font="bold", bg="#010523", fg="white")
public_broadcast.grid(row=0, column=1)


_id = Label(header_frame, text="MY ID: 0013A20041EFD12C",
            font="10", bg="#010523", fg="grey")
_id.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10)

# ********************end of header frame*************************



# label1 = tk.Label(frame_main, text="Label 1", fg="green")
# label1.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(5, 0), sticky='nw')

# label2 = tk.Label(frame_main, text="Label 2", fg="blue")
# label2.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=(5, 0), sticky='nw')

# label3 = tk.Label(frame_main, text="Label 3", fg="red")
# label3.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=5, sticky='nw')

# Create a frame for the canvas with non-zero row&column weights
frame_canvas = tk.Frame(frame_main)
frame_canvas.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=(5, 0), sticky='nw')
frame_canvas.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame_canvas.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
# Set grid_propagate to False to allow 5-by-5 buttons resizing later
frame_canvas.grid_propagate(False)

# Add a canvas in that frame
canvas = tk.Canvas(frame_canvas, bg="yellow")
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")

# Link a scrollbar to the canvas
vsb = tk.Scrollbar(frame_canvas, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

# Create a frame to contain the buttons
frame_buttons = tk.Frame(canvas, bg="blue")


# Add 9-by-5 buttons to the frame
last_frame_row = 3



frame_canvas.config(width=400, height=300)


# Entering self msg frame with text
def add_msg_frame():
    global last_frame_row
    msg = "This is a test msg"
    # msg = e.get()
    # e.delete(0, END)
    new_frame = Frame(frame_buttons, bg="#4857a8", borderwidth=0)
    new_frame.grid(row=last_frame_row, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky='e', pady=5)
    last_frame_row += 1
    
    new_label = Label(new_frame, text=msg, font="10", bg="#4857a8", fg="white")
    new_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
    
    canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame_buttons, anchor='nw')
    


def add_reply_msg(device_id="0983ADFCD9827sd", msg="this is a sample message"):
    global last_frame_row
    new_frame = Frame(frame_buttons, bg="#1f243f", borderwidth=0)
    new_frame.grid(row=last_frame_row, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='w', pady=5)
    last_frame_row += 1
    
    new_label = Label(new_frame, text=device_id, bg="#1f243f", font="10", fg="#a6a6a6")
    new_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
    
    new_label2 = Label(new_frame, text=msg, font="10", bg="#1f243f", fg="white")
    new_label2.grid(row=1, column=0)



# Update buttons frames idle tasks to let tkinter calculate buttons sizes
# for i in range(30):
#     add_msg_frame()
add_reply_msg()
add_reply_msg()
add_msg_frame()

frame_buttons.update_idletasks()


# Set the canvas scrolling region
canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"), yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame_buttons, anchor='nw')
canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))

# # Entry
eFrame = Frame(root, width=400, height=100)
eFrame.grid(row=1000, column=0)

e = Entry(eFrame, width=50)
e.grid(row=0, column=0)

ebtn = Button(eFrame, text="Send", bg="skyblue", command=add_msg_frame)
ebtn.grid(row=0, column=1)

# Launch the GUI
root.mainloop()
```

Please give me suggestions that how can i enable scrollbar when add a frame by clicking the send button.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the `scrollregion` whenever you add or modify things on the canvas.

Comment: it is working fine when i added this line of code inside my frame addition function: canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"), yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

Answer (score 1):

`frame_buttons` will be resized when items are added to it, so you need to update the `scrollregion` of the canvas in this case via `bind('<Configure>', ...)`.  Also it is better to call `canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame_buttons, anchor='nw')` once outside the function `add_msg_frame()`:

```py
...
# Create a frame to contain the buttons
frame_buttons = tk.Frame(canvas, bg="blue")
# call canvas.create_window(...) once here
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame_buttons, anchor='nw')
# update scrollregion of canvas whenever the frame is resized
frame_buttons.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all')))
...
```

Comment: it is working by this line: canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"), yscrollcommand=vsb.set)